# cant display message after force download in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to display a  message after the user has forced a download. What happens is I cant display a  message after the dialog box appears regardless of what option is chosen from the dialog box.
I didnt understand the previous post I found on the matter and I coudnt find anything in the docs about this .

```
  public function ...
     $this->downloadexcel($filename);
      //this message never gets displayed
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Select another file to download . '));
   ...
public function downloadexcel($filename=null) {



     $fullPath='Excelcontacts'.  DS .$filename;

     //the dialog appears and it works fine
      $this->response->file($fullPath, array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));

      //this message never gets displayed
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Select another file to download . '));

    // return $this->response;


}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html
[Force download file in CakePHP 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338343/force-download-file-in-cakephp-2-1)

Comment: Of course this message does not get displayed, because the HTML page that the user was viewing in their browser stays the same. You can not make a file download and output a new HTML page at the same time. So this message would only be displayed on the _next_ page the user visits. If you want to display a message “with” the download, then you can only do that by going to another HTML page first, and then trigger the actual download from there (f.e. via a meta refresh or JavaScript).

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. I am currently displaying the download from its own webpage ctp anyway. I am using cakephp so it triggers the code in the controller as shown above.

Comment: _“so it triggers the code in the controller as shown above”_ – yes, and that code sends the download file as response. The flash message is put into the session, and it will only be read from there and output on the next regular HTML page the user visits.

Comment: I f you have a look at my original code you see the message wont be sent from calling the download. Basically I cant display anything after a download as in cakephp this is a redirect

Comment: It doesn’t matter _where_ you set that message … the browser has send a request to the server, and the server responded with the data of a file to be downloaded – so the HTML page that the user was seeing when the clicked the link for the download _stays the same_. You can not change it from the server, because you can not send two different resources (download file and a new HTML document) in response to one single request. And therefor the message stays stored in the session until the user requests a new HTML page from the server …

Comment: you cant request a new page and see any message as it is a flash message . I dont see this flash anywhere on any page afterwards. If you can do this please show me the code as it isnt working the way you are saying. cakephp isnt exactly php so is this the issue?

Comment: I don’t know how specifically cake handles flash messages, but usually this is implemented in a way that they are output the next time a new HTML document is created and send to the client. But you are not generating a new HTML page here, but you are returning a download file _instead_. So you _can not_ get those messages in response to the _same_ request.

Comment: Assuming that cake does not simply delete these messages once the current request is handled, but keeps them until the next HTML document is output, you should see them on the next page requested by the browser (whatever page that may be). But having them show up “simultaneously” together with the download is technically impossible.

Comment: Forget messages as anything like a debug or variable wont display after a call to download. cakephp doesnt work like this where you go to another page and the previous session flash message apears? Again, please show the code if you can do this in cakephp?

Comment: I just need an example because you are not talking cakephp lingo here, as you might be confused with php way of doing things for a download?

Comment: I am not confused with that at all. This works pretty much the same whatever technique or framework you use to implement it. But you don’t seem to understand the actual background of the problem here. I already told you that it is _technically impossible_ to have a download _and_ a change of the current HTML page the user is on in response to _one single request_ – it doesn’t matter if it is cake or any other framework, that’s just how HTTP and a request-response cycle works. And what the alternative way of implementing this could be, I already said in my very first comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69051/discussion-between-ajt-and-cbroe).